# indexOf condition not working

Tags: javascript

I have a page where I have random text that displays on refresh, but I'm also attempting to use localStorage to save what text has already been viewed to avoid duplicates.

The problem I'm encountering is with this condition:

```
if ((localStorage.getItem("viewedTips") !== null) && (viewedTips.indexOf(n) == -1)) {...}
```

viewedTips.indexOf(n) == -1 does not behave the way I anticipate.  The idea is that it will check whether a string (n) is already stored in var viewedTips, and if so, will not execute my block of code.

I confirmed that viewedTips is storing my previously used strings correctly, but even if "n" is a duplicate value found in viewedTips, my code will still execute ignoring the fact that indexOf should not be returning "-1".

What's even more baffling is that if I set "(viewedTips.indexOf(n) !== -1))" (note the use of "!"), my block of code will not execute.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

**UPDATE:**

Artem caught my mistake.  Thanks, Artem!

Comment: post a complete example: place a `var viewedTips = ["value", "here"];` with the actual value you are feeding into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use old viewedTips value, try

```
if ((localStorage.getItem("viewedTips") !== null) && (localStorage.getItem("viewedTips").indexOf(n) == -1)) {...}
```

Comment: @habib_101 no problem! Don't forget to mark it as a solution.